# QGIS 3.26.3 tries to load non-existent "qgispython" library at initial start after setup on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, qgis-server

After setting up a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS installation, I tried to install QGIS according to the official documents.

In step 2.1 [in this documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems) it is said, that I need to run the following command to see, if the installation is working:

> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi

However in doing so, I get these error messages (Output in Debug Mode):

> loaded library "/usr/lib/qgis/server/libqgispython.so"
> QLibraryPrivate::unload succeeded on "/usr/lib/qgis/server/libqgispython.so"
>
> "Loading native module /usr/lib/qgis/server/libwmts.so"
> loaded library "/usr/lib/qgis/server/libwmts.so"
> loaded library "/usr/lib/qgispython"

What makes me question this is:

- In the first error, the library "libqgispython.so" is unloaded directly after loading it whereas the other loaded modules are only unloaded right before the operation aborts
- In the second error, the operation tries to load library "/usr/lib/qgispython" however there is no such library with that name in "/usr/lib"

Before running the command I also added the QGIS repository "qgis.org/ubuntu" according [to this manual](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) and also installed python-qgis directly with qgis, qgis-plugin-grass and qgis-server.

Does anyone have a hunch, what the cause of this could be?